# Setup & Deployment Project different then Source

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

I created this program that works fine in VS12 and compiles and runs fines. However I created a setup and deployment project for it using the InstallShield wizard. The installation is successfull on my test machine however I can not get my EventHandler working it is a service instance that i parse the events on.

```
class EventHandler : EventHandlerService.EventHandlerCCServicePortType
{
    public EventHandlerService.handleEventResponse1 handleEvent(EventHandlerService.handleEventRequest eventMsg)
    {
        EventHandlerService.handleEventResponse1 resp = new EventHandlerService.handleEventResponse1();
        EventHandlerService.handleEventResponse respInfo = new EventHandlerService.handleEventResponse();


        resp.handleEventResponse = respInfo;

        respInfo.@return = true;
        Main instance = Main.getFormInstance();
        instance.setPhoneStatus(eventMsg.handleEvent.@event);

        return (resp);

    }
}


static public Main getFormInstance()
{
    return (instance);
}



delegate void setPhoneStatusCB(EventHandlerService.standardEventMsg eventMsg);

public void setPhoneStatus(EventHandlerService.standardEventMsg eventMsg)
    {
            DisplayEvent(eventMsg);
            if (eventMsg.eventType == EventHandlerService.standardEventMsgEventType.CALL_EVENT)
            {
                if (eventMsg.callEvent.objectId == Int64.Parse(Peridot.Properties.Settings.Default.OIGPhoneObjID.ToString()))
                {
                    Peridot.Properties.Settings.Default.OIGPhoneLastEvent = eventMsg.callEvent.type.ToString();
                    if (eventMsg.callEvent.callState.ToString().Length > 0)
                    {
                        Peridot.Properties.Settings.Default.OIGPhoneState = eventMsg.callEvent.callState.ToString();
                    }

                    if (eventMsg.callEvent.localCallId.ToString().Length > 0)
                    {
                        Peridot.Properties.Settings.Default.OIGPhoneCallId = eventMsg.callEvent.localCallId.ToString();
                        writeToLogFile("Getting OIG Phone Call ID EventMsg: " + eventMsg.callEvent.localCallId.ToString(), "SYSTEM");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Peridot.Properties.Settings.Default.OIGPhoneCallId = "";
                        writeToLogFile("Getting OIG Phone Call ID Failied! EventMsg: " + eventMsg.callEvent.localCallId.ToString(), "SYSTEM");
                    }

                }
        }
 }
```

}

Seems like setPhoneStatus never gets called and the Instance is never sent, this only happens on the deployed program and not in the development. Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you make sure you added all files and dependencies in the deployment project?

Comment: Yeah I thought it was something like that, I ended up changing the Build action on my EventHandler Class now everything is good